# Does this series admit a closed form solution?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider the following series where $a, b$ are real numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} e^{a k + b k^2} $$

Does it admit a closed form or, otherwise "nice", expression?

This form comes up when trying to compute the expectation of $\log(1 + e^{-x})$ where $x$ is normally distributed.

---

How do I get there?

$$\log(1 + e^{-x}) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k} e^{-k x}$$

and

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-k x} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}}{\sigma \sqrt{\tau}} = e^{\frac{1}{2}k(k \sigma^2 - 2\mu)}$$

I haven't particularly looked at convergence for now, and with $\sigma^2 >0$ it's obviously not looking good, but I'm trying to manipulate this thing formally and just see what happens, maybe we can land back on our feet somehow...

Comment: Difficult to compute for $k=0$. :)

Comment: @JohnB I changed the sum to start at $k=1$ to avoid that problem :)

Comment: How did you arrive at $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}k e^{ak+bk^2}$ when trying to compute that expectation?

Comment: if $b>0$ the series diverges

Comment: Hint: Derivative of $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{a k+b k^2}}{k}$ with respect to "a" gives for $q=e^b$ and a = b = 1 e.g. "$\frac{\vartheta _2(0,q)-2 \sqrt[4]{q}}{2 \sqrt[4]{q}}$", with $\vartheta _2(0,q)$ the elliptic theta function. Mean we are seeking for a general solution and finally integrate with respect to a.

Comment: I realized, that the way I sketched above works in general for a=b and a closed form solution can be found. The other cases I doubt.